# How can you have two filenames and use either to serve it?

Tags: php, file, rename

I am letting users upload a file and i am storing the name of the original file name in one field and the other the renamed name of the file to avoid duplicates and other risks.  So when i let them download it, i want them to be able to download it as the original name but when its on our servers i want to use the renamed version.

Sample:

$original = the name the user gave the file

$renamed = the name we gave the file

```
  header('Content-type: application/octet-stream'); // concatenation
   header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=$original"); // double quotes
  $filename="../../../../docs/doc/$renamed";
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filename));
   ob_clean();
    flush();
  readfile($renamed); // no quotes needed
```

i tried doing this but since the original name is stored in the database and the actual file name is the renamed one how can i achieve this?

Comment: Store both names in the database. Send the original name in the header, read the renamed name off the disk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=" . urlencode($original)); 
readfile($renamed);
```

Comment: Hey i used it but when i download it says: Couldn’t open the file. It may be corrupt or a file format that Preview doesn’t recognize. See my question i updated with what i am using.

Comment: Uh, if the filename you have to use is different (`$filename`?) then you should be using that instead.

Comment: i am not sure i follow.  very confused.  $orignal is the original name of the file $renamed is the new new name we gave..

Comment: thats where the file is stored. check the variable i have   $filename="../../../../docs/doc/$renamed";

Comment: Read your edit. Read it again. Read it a third time until you see where you're using `$renamed` instead of `$filename`.

Comment: Got it! thanks.  And sorry.  I am a new programmer so don't have the keen eyes yet.